# set Chrome Extension to be a canvas?

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, html5-canvas

I am working on a Chrome Extension and I created an HTML file to have the canvas for the icon.  When I run the html file it is perfectly fine, but it doesn't seem to want to be in the `manifest.json` file.

**Code in** `manifest.json`

```
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.html"
}
```

But if I change `icon.html` to `icon.png` for an image it is fine.

*If you need information about the canvas I am using I can give it to you.*

Comment: Have you tried to use `chrome.browserAction.setIcon` instead: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setIcon

Comment: @gui47 so I'm guessing that's javascript, now how do i import that to the extension?  Do i need to create a `js` file and put it in the `manifest.json` file?

Comment: First use the HTML5 Canvas element. Then create a canvas, add images and/or text to it, then pass the canvas image data like `chrome.browserAction.setIcon({imageData: imageData});`

Comment: Yes. you need to create a background.js and specify it in your manifest file: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages

Comment: @gui47 i did all the steps you said, and added in my script tag in the canvas file that `chrome.browserAction` thing but i am getting an error when i refresh the extension saying `Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-zZQmVrFiMrthN4EPMFAYtZ4s7AcA1DpZlVONBxpd_mw='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.` and basically what i got from that is i cant use the script tag? am i supposed to add a permission?

Comment: oh nevermind, i found this https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_migration_to_manifest_v2#inline_scripts, thanks though!

Comment: @gui47 **Avoid answering questions in comments!** Please form an answer out of your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `chrome.browserAction.setIcon` instead in the background.js: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setIcon

Process like: First use the HTML5 Canvas element. Then create a canvas, add images and/or text to it, then pass the canvas image data like 
`chrome.browserAction.setIcon({imageData: imageData});`